# Cómo extraer un consecutivo alfanumérico de un texto en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, procesamiento-de-texto

Tengo un dataframe con una columna de textos, allí se encuentra un consecutivo alfanumérico el cual necesito extraer.

**Ejemplo:** 
"solicitud de informacion de **bab123**"
o "**bcb10c** solicitud de informacion"
o "solicitud 404520 **kat12d** informacion"
o "solicitud 404520**jla125** informacion"

Requiero extraer los consecutivos **bab123**, **bcb10c**, **kat12d**, **jla125**  en una columna nueva del dataframe.

Gracias.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te recomiendo que mires [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. 
También, aprovecha y haz el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

utiliza expresiones regulares, se utilizan para encontrar patrones con cierta estructura en cadenas de texto, para ello lo primero es encontrar dicha estructura, por tus ejemplos supongo que comienza con 3 letras minúsculas y otros 3 caracteres que pueden ser o bien 2 dígitos y una letra o 3 letras. la expresión regular queda de la siguiente manera

```
r"[a-z]{3}[0-9]{2}[a-z0-9]{1}"
```

La siguiente expresion se divide en tres partes.

- [a-z]{3} Esto nos indica que debe aparecer exactamente 3 letras minúscula
- [0-9]{2} Esto nos indica que debe aparecer exactamente 2 digitos
- [a-z0-9]{1} Y esto nos indica que puede aparecer o una letra o un digito exactamente 1 vez.

El código quedaría algo asi

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("archivo.csv")
df["col"] = df["col"].map(lambda x: re.findall(r"[a-z]{3}[0-9]{2}[a-z0-9]{1}", str(x)))
```

la función `findall` regresa una lista con todas las coincidencias encontradas en la cadena por si hay mas de una coincidencia no se pierda, si no, puedes usar el método `match`